# mysql - sum field by date range and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id | sent_time         | status | campaignId |
---+-------------------+--------+------------+
1  |2013-12-26 00:00:00|  sent  |     12     |
---+-------------------+--------+------------+    
2  |2013-12-26 00:00:00|  sent  |     12     |
---+-------------------+--------+------------+    
3  |2013-12-26 00:00:00|  sent  |     11     |
---+-------------------+--------+------------+    
4  |2018-10-21 00:00:00|  draft |     13     |
---+-------------------+--------+------------+    
5  |2018-10-21 00:00:00|  draft |     14     |
---+-------------------+--------+------------+    
6  |2018-10-21 00:00:00|  draft |     14     |
---+-------------------+--------+------------+
```

I want to display the data between date from ***sent_time*** field range and sum the 'sent' status who get the same 'campaignId'
and this is my query:

```
    SELECT DATE(sent_time) AS date_sent_time, SUM(status='sent') AS total_sent_status
    FROM sms_table WHERE (DATE(sent_time) BETWEEN 2014-08-26 AND 2014-09-30)
    AND campaignId = 12 GROUP BY DATE(sent_time)
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you want to get the number of rows where the status equals 'sent' or am I missing something?

Comment: @andy I want to get the number of rows where the status is sent and the campaignId = 12 and also group by sent_time, is it possible sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  DATE(sent_time) AS sent_date,
  COUNT(id) AS total_sent_status
FROM sms_table
WHERE
  status = 'sent'
  AND campaignID = 12
  AND sent_time BETWEEN '2014-08-26 00:00:00' AND '2014-09-30 23:59:59'
GROUP BY sent_date
```

A few notes:

- You can just move status filter to WHERE clause to simplify things.  Make sure you have index on this column
- You should not use a calculated value for comparison in a where clause like you are doing with `DATE(sent_time)` as this prevents use of index.  You can simply use `00:00:00` and `23:59:59` to work around this, or better yet, if your `sent_time` field really has all time components of `00:00:00` as shown in your sample data, just make it a date field.

Comment: I have this record in my table: campaignId: 12 sent_time: 2014-09-22 16:56:01 status: sent, but it returns nothing sir

Comment: @junior I did have typo above which I fixed (extra space after `DATE` on second line.  BUt were you getting an emptry result set or was the query itself not working (i.e. syntax error)?

Comment: this part I need only the date part: sent_time BETWEEN '2014-08-26 00:00:00' AND '2014-09-30 23:59:59' so I changed it into SELECT DATE(sent_time) AS sent_date, COUNT(id) AS total_sent_status FROM sms_table WHERE status = 'sent' AND campaignId = 12 AND DATE(sent_time) BETWEEN 2014-08-26 AND 2014-09-30 GROUP BY sent_date and its not working

Comment: @junior  Then why are you saying my solution doesn't work if you changed it?  I specifically included the time portion for a reason - so that you could actually use an index on `date_sent` when executing the query as opposed to use `DATE(date_sent)` which would not be able to use an index.

Comment: Oh my bad .. I forgot to put the date between '' .. sorry sir it works now, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can move the condition on `status='sent'` to the WHERE clause and add `COUNT(id)` to the SELECT as follows:

```
SELECT DATE(sent_time) AS date_sent_time, COUNT(id) AS total_sent_status
FROM sms_table
WHERE sent_time BETWEEN '2014-08-26 00:00:00' AND '2014-09-30 23:59:59'
AND campaignId = 12 
AND status = 'sent'
GROUP BY date_sent_time
```

You should indeed not use functions in the where clause as this can prevent MySQL from using an index. Also note that you can use aliases in the GROUP BY clause.

Here is an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1f779/1/0).

Comment: I have this record in my table:

campaignId: 12
sent_time: 2014-09-22 16:56:01
status: sent

I try your query, but still not working :(

Comment: Oh my bad .. I forgot to put the date between '' .. sorry sir it works now, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can group my multiple columns...

```
... GROUP BY DATE(sent_time), campaignId
```

To include in the breakdown.

Or as a complete query...

```
SELECT DATE(sent_time) AS date_sent_time, campaignId, SUM(status='sent') AS total_sent_status
FROM sms_table WHERE (DATE(sent_time) BETWEEN 2014-08-26 AND 2014-09-30)
GROUP BY DATE(sent_time), campaignId
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the count of records where the status is 'Sent' for CampaignID 12 that occured between 2014-08-26 and 2014-09-30

```
SELECT 
    DATE(sent_time) AS date_sent_time, 
    COUNT(status) AS total_sent_status
FROM sms_table 
WHERE 
    DATE(sent_time) BETWEEN '2014-08-26' AND '2014-09-30' AND
    campaignId = 12 AND
    status = 'Sent'
GROUP BY sent_time
```